# no loading circle in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

i was trying to fill **ListFragment** with **JSON** content, which i parse with my **JSONParcer(extends AsyncTask**) class. I've also wrote **CustomAdapter(extends Arrayadapter)** because of specific list row layout. All works just fine except for there's **no loading circle** in the **ListFragment** while it's loading (as it should be by default). How can i get it back?

Here's my adapter code:

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> 
{
  private final Activity context;
  private final ListItem[] data;

  public CustomAdapter(Activity context,ListItem[] itemz) 
  {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item,itemz);
    this.context = context;
    this.data = itemz;
  }

  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtBody = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.body);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picture);

        txtTitle.setText(data[position].getTitle());
        txtBody.setText(data[position].getBody());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(data[position].getPicture());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `ListFragment` call `setListShown(false);` to hide the `ListView` and show the loading icon. 
When you want to show your items (after loading them, processing, whatever) call:

```
if (isResumed())
    setListShown(true);
else
    setListShownNoAnimation(true);
```

Comment: the content of the list is still visible after the loading even if there's setListShown(false); goes before it

Comment: @user3090300 - make sure you call setListAdapter(adapter); before you call setListShown(false);

Answer (score 0):

You may fill the ListFragment with an AsyncTask, like this:

```
private class  fillFragmentList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Heavy code
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Set the list adapter
        setListAdapter(yourCustomAdapter);
    }
}
```

this class should be in the class that extends ListFragment.